# How to position a newly added Add-On in the outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, ribbon

I have created a new add-on for Outlook and I created a setup file aslo. while installing my Add-On, The ribbon appearing in the last. I want to position it first. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of custom tabs on a Ribbon by using the Tab Collection Editor

[Click here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608600.aspx)